# Shooting GameObjects in Vuforia

Tags: vuforia

**HI  Actually I want to throw gameobjects like Shooting Bullets But it does not work. It throws unlimited gameObjects without any wait. Here is My script on ARCamera.

```
//Script starts 
var prefabBullet : Transform; 
var speed : float; 
var gameObjects : GameObject[]; 
function Update () { Invoke("Shoot", 2.0f); } 
function Shoot () { yield WaitForSeconds(3); 
     var instanceBullet=Instantiate(prefabBullet,transform.position,Quaternion.identity);     
     instanceBullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward*speed) ;
     SomeFunction(); 
}
function SomeFunction() { 
     gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player");
     for(var i = 0 ; i < gameObjects.length ; i ++) 
        Destroy(gameObjects[i]); 
}
```

========================================================================

I want to throw gameObjects between some time elapsing.**

Answer (score 0):

```
function Update () { Invoke("Shoot", 2.0f); } 
function Shoot () { yield WaitForSeconds(3);
```

All you are doing here is putting in a 5second delay on the call, but the call is still being made every Update frame, so you get a 5 second delay before the first call, but then they will be every frame.

set up a boolean to control when the shooting happens.

```
var fire : bool = true;
function Update()
{
    if (fire)
    {
       Shoot();
       fire = false;
    }
}
function Shoot()
{
   yield WaitForSeconds(3);
   //do you projectile stuff
   fire = true;
}
```